# Filter time array in python with datetime library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

**I want to filter my list of time string elements with the help of python datetime library.**

I have a array like -

```
time_Arr = ["0:0:16","3:59:9","2:50:32","23:46:52","20:30:12"]
```

I want to make it be filtered from the ascending order (0:0:0 - 23:59:59) accordingly.

Also i will have bulk of data (array should be almost containing more than 5k ) so what will be most efficient for this?

How can i achieve this in python?

the resulting array should be something like -

```
["0:0:16","2:50:32","3:59:9","20:30:12","23:46:52"]
```

Comment: You mean to sort this array?

Comment: this is not "filter", this is called as "sort"

Answer (score 3):

This will convert the strings to datetime, sort them then output a list with your desired format.

```
from datetime import datetime
time_Arr = ["0:0:16","3:59:9","2:50:32","23:46:52","20:30:12"]
sorted(time_Arr, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

> `['0:0:16', '2:50:32', '3:59:9', '20:30:12', '23:46:52']`

Answer (score 2):

Use datetime to parse the time then sort:

```py
from datetime import datetime
time_Arr = ["0:0:16","3:59:9","2:50:32","23:46:52","20:30:12"]
time_Arr = sorted([datetime.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S") for t in time_Arr])
# [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 16),
#  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 50, 32),
#  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 3, 59, 9),
#  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 20, 30, 12),
#  datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 46, 52)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime 
sorted([datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S") for time in time_Arr])
```